# What is the actual advantage in collecting hats?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

I really wonder about these mysterious hats. Why should we collect them?

Comment: Okay I see! This is just a sort of StackExchange tradition, very nice!

Comment: Hats exist to increase traffic (ad impressions) during a time of the year when traffic is generally low.

Comment: @Jeffrey not sure the "ad impressions" bit checks out though. Most users who participate in hats are likely to be above 200 reputation points, so they won't see ads

Comment: related: [The problem with extrinsic motivation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/42481/165773)

Comment: @Pekka웃 As the [privileges page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads) itself says, only some of the ads are hidden, while others continue to be shown.

Comment: You cannot ask such a thing: hats are the only important things around these sites.

Comment: It's so your avatar's head won't go cold.

Comment: Each hat collected gives you a +1 in the Stack Fu skill.

Comment: I have a better question: Why *offer* hats?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Hats have no value beyond holiday cheer. They do not incur any privileges and they're all going away in early January.

They're a little like badges, except these can be used to keep your ears warm.

Comment: Hats can have value beyond the holidays, just look at [my gravatar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pv5mS.png?s=328) :)

Comment: They are the most (if not the only) valuable things around these sites

Comment: "they're all going away in early January". Can't I really keep my warm Yeti suit for the cold spring months? :(

Answer (score 34):

Winter Bash Hats are the virtual version of a Stack Overflow office tradition as explained in the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CDi_nj1-G6U).

The actual advantage is to increase community engagement through gamification.

Answer (score 5):

It will just show your participation on Stack Overflow. Collecting hats is just a trend. It will not increase your reputations.

Answer (score 4):

It is just for a kind of game or like a participation for fun in which user can feel that they collects no. of hat in this duration.

Answer (score -19):

Collecting hats also indirectly helps to increase your reputation points. To get more hats you need to answer.

Comment: Lots of hats are for things like voting or giving bounties which do not increase reputation.

Comment: This is actually true. The more hats you want to collect, the more you will stay on SO and browse around. Yes, maybe not all actions will get you reputation, but you will stay at SO longer then before. Not sure why so many down-votes.

Comment: @Aleks the second sentence is absolutely false, for one.

Comment: @Rob Explain me how? Don't just put statement and expect that it is true without any arguments. I have put arguments why it is true, and you just said - it is false. But why it is false? How come it DOESN'T help you INDIRECTLY help you increase your reputation if you stay longer trying to win at least some of the hats - by adding comments, posting answers etc. where some of which WILL earn you a reputation points? Tell me why it is "absolutely" false?

Comment: @Aleks I thought it was self explanatory: you do not need to answer anything to earn hats.

Comment: @Rob It is not self explanatory. You don't need to answer, but you COULD answer something to earn some new hats. It says "indirectly", not directly!

Comment: @Aleks It's StackOverflow. Inference is lost on most people here who take everything completely literally. :)