# What would happen if someone collected all the hats?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

Are there some hidden gems or hats for users who collect *all* the hats?

I guess that happens very rarely, but who knows what Stack Overflow has prepared for that situation.

Comment: i think nothing special ! it goes away next moth i guess just this period

Comment: A unicorn with a giant S will knock on their door...

Comment: Guess you just gotta *catch 'em all* to find out…

Comment: 99 hats on SO, you take one, and you have 98 hats left on SO ;)

Comment: @rene Jeff is a unicorn now?!

Comment: Don't forget the Ditto hat which just looks like another hat :)

Comment: If there was a "hidden gem of hats" that you didn't have yet then by logical deduction you have not collected "*all* the hats". So your question is meaningless.

Comment: [I am your father's brother's nephew's cousin's former roommate.](https://youtu.be/CZd_YyFzPD0?t=20s) - Spaceballs

Comment: @DavidPostill yes, for the hats part, but if you read the question without extracting parts that suits you, I have asked if there are some other hidden gems not just the hats.

Comment: Wait, Jon Skeet doesn't have them all yet? Is he just slacking off this year?

Comment: If there would be a hat for collecting all hats, nobody could get it:(

Comment: You probably get mailed a shirt or something.

Comment: bragging rights!

Comment: There is a hat for collecting 11 hats :)) http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/011

Comment: You get an email with an infographic explaining what the front door is and what's on the other side.

Comment: His name will be automatically changed to Jon Skeet.

Comment: I would guess nothing.  Your hats will be wiped forever at the end of the time period anyways. :(

Comment: Hopefully, among any other effects, "I hate hats" would be permanently removed from their winter bash menu.

Comment: At least one person collected all hats in last year's Winterbash. It will be harder this year due to the "on SO" and "not on SO" hats.

Comment: Errr.. hat overflow?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the actual advantage in collecting hats?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340309/what-is-the-actual-advantage-in-collecting-hats)

Comment: @AndrewMorton I liked the `HatOverflowError` answer the best. If you would like, you could post it ;)

Comment: @Aleks I tried and tried to find a suitable photo, but my overflowing-pile-of-hats-fu is weak today.

Comment: Probably he breaks his neck!

Comment: I got all the hats. For the last one I was prompted to choose between a blue pill and a red pill. I could tell what has happened then and how it changed my life. But then I'm supposed to shoot you.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You will get a **HatOverflow** Error.

[image]

Comment: Maybe not the most up-voted answer, if there is a correct answer on this :) but I liked it ;)

Answer (score 35):

Stackoverflow will get a NullpointerException.

Comment: Missed chance for a Stack Overflow Stack Overflow.

Comment: HatOverflow Exception?

Comment: HatOverflowException or OutOfAllHatsException?

Comment: How come @Aleks hasn't _accepted_ this answer...

Comment: @T-Heron There are a lot of funny answers. In a way it is quite nice to read them, so didn't want to set as `answered` just yet, as it is still fun for now to see the answers, but I will mark it.

Answer (score 4):

Clearly you would win a new hat for that, meaning you would THEN have collected all the hats...and they would then give you another one for achieiving that, and then...oh crap.  @Andrew Morton is right. Hat Overflow.

Answer (score 4):

Chuck Norris will gift you his hat.

[image]

Comment: hehe, nice hat :))

Comment: Downvoted as "gift" is not a verb

Comment: @NicholasShanks Oh yes it is!

Answer (score 3):

First, your clock will forever be set to 18:00 (at least on StackOverflow). Also, you will have to drink tea for the rest of your life.

But it won't matter because you will be sentenced to have your head taken off by the Queen of Hearts.

Answer (score -11):

Quoting Bhargav Rao [from moderator election Q\A](https://stackoverflow.com/election/8#post-40473714), who is now an elected moderator

> P.S. I won Winterbash 2015 and there's a saying that WB winners will make good mods (which came true in 2014).

You will need approximately 700 rep points and if you win the winter bash you can run for moderator on 2017.